# React search filter system

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to filter name of products with a filter system using react. Products come from a database, I do a query with laravel and fetch it in react (I receive an array of objects). My problem is retrieve the 'name' attribute, put it into an array and filter it.

```
 const [filterList, setFilterList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getlist', { method: 'GET' })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setFilterList(res)
      }).catch()

  }, []);

  if (filterList === undefined) {
    return <>Still loading...</>;
  }
  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value === "") {
      setFilterList(filterList);
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      filterList.forEach(List => {
        var nome = []
        var nome = List.name
        console.log(List.name)
        const filteredValues = nome.filter(

          (nome) =>
            nome.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        );
        setFilterList(filteredValues);
      });
```

my error is:
nome.filter is not a function
any suggestion?

Comment: It's not clear what `nome` is suppose to be. You declare it once to be an empty array, then immediately redeclare it as `List.name` which would presumably be a string, which would not have a `filter` method attached to it, as the error notes. I suggest not using `forEach` but rather `filter` against `filterList` as in `setFilterList(filterList.filter(product => produce.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())))`.

Comment: You are declaring nome three different times. Once as an empty array and again as list.name, and then you are naming each item of the filterList nome.

Answer (score 0):

If filterList is an array of objects, you don't need to forEach, you can just use the filter:

```
const filteredValues = filterList.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```